# How to listen componentShown/componentHidden events better than ComponentListener?

Tags: java, swing, events, components, listener

I want to be informed if componentShown/componentHidden event occured. I use ComponentListener, but it doesn't work as good as I need. I have found this information in official Swing tutorial:

> The component-hidden and
>   component-shown events occur only as
>   the result of calls to a Component 's
>   setVisible method. For example, a
>   window might be miniaturized into an
>   icon (iconified) without a
>   component-hidden event being fired.

So I supose I have to find another solution. So how to listen **every** componentShown/componentHidden event?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to do this with a single listener.

You can also use a WindowListener to listen for windowIconified.